# How to add referral program in flutter using firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So I am a newbie in flutter but I want to implement a referral program which can help me! please

Comment: You should focus on a specific programming problem when asking a question on Stack Overflow, not how to implement an entire program or feature. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), the site tour, and especially [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) Once you do, you should edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [firebase_dynamic_links](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links#-installing-tab-)  to implement a referral program, For more information visit [official page](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links)

**How Create Dynamic Link?**

```
final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
  uriPrefix: 'https://abc123.app.goo.gl',
  link: Uri.parse('https://example.com/'),
  androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
      packageName: 'com.example.android',
      minimumVersion: 125,
  ),
  iosParameters: IosParameters(
      bundleId: 'com.example.ios',
      minimumVersion: '1.0.1',
      appStoreId: '123456789',
  ),
  googleAnalyticsParameters: GoogleAnalyticsParameters(
      campaign: 'example-promo',
      medium: 'social',
      source: 'orkut',
  ),
  itunesConnectAnalyticsParameters: ItunesConnectAnalyticsParameters(
    providerToken: '123456',
    campaignToken: 'example-promo',
  ),
  socialMetaTagParameters:  SocialMetaTagParameters(
    title: 'Example of a Dynamic Link',
    description: 'This link works whether app is installed or not!',
  ),
);

final Uri dynamicUrl = await parameters.buildUrl();
```

**How to Receive Dynamic Links?**

```
final PendingDynamicLinkData data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
final Uri deepLink = data?.link;
```